# Aligning the menu bar closer to web

Tags: html, css, menubar

I'm a newbie to web development and I'm learning HTML and CSS right now. I'm using Firefox 18 and I want to have a menu bar close to the browser's header (pretty much like Facebook's blue menu bar).

Though I have created the menu bar, I have issues aligning it. My questions:
 1. How do I reduce the space on Top, right and left, so that the menu bar fits snugly into the Firefox? I tried padding but it only alters the space between items on the menu bar and not how the bar is aligned.
 2. Will resizing the browser have any effect on the way the bar is displayed? Is it a browser property or can I un-resize the menu bar from the code I've written?

Thanks!

Comment: post some code so we can take a look please. Use a tool like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) in order to create a version we can see.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cgVyv/embedded/result/ Thanks!

Comment: it only worked there because 'jsfiddle' has a style reset, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

at the top of your css

--- or ---

use a reset

> The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in
>   things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings,
>   and so on.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Thanks Eric! The reset worked. Henceforth, I shall add them in all my style sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Web developer Step One: Become very friendly with [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) and Chrome's developer tools feature [F12]. These tools allow you to quickly see what element has the styles applied that are causing you strife. You can then make changes in the page to test your fix.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should google for some reset.css or normalize.css cause you are probably experiencing problems with the browsers default styling. There one from Eric Meyer is very popular and can be found here http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ but there are others available.

What this does is remove all styling the browser applies by default. It is probably a good idea to include this in everey page you make from now on, to make your styling consistent in all browsers. I never go without it!